# Pressing source in Rstudio only shows the working directory instead of running the code

Tags: r

I was following a Youtube video that was going through how to create an interactive menu in R. I did tweak some stuff from the original video, but nothing drastic that would make or break the code (at least I think so).

The youtube video I watched:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaPBpJArh0M

This is my code:

```
inputNumber <- function(prompt) {
  # Usage: num = inputNumber(prompt)
  # 
  # Displays prompt and asks for a number. 
  # Repeats until user inputs a valid number.
  while(TRUE) {
    num = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(readline(prompt)))
    if(!is.na(num)) {
      break
    }
  }
}

displayMenu <- function(options) {
  # Usage: choice = displayMenu(options)
  # 
  # Displays a menu of options,
  # ask the user to choose an item,
  # and return the number of the menu item chosen.
  # 
  # Input   options   Menu options (cell array of strings)
  # Output  choice    Chosen option (integer)

  # Display menu options
  for (i in 1:length(options)) {
    cat(sprintf("%d. %s\n", i, options[i]))
  }

  # Gets a valid menu choice
  choice <- 0
  while (!any(choice == 1:length(options))) {
    choice = inputNumber("Please choose a menu item: ")
  }

  return(choice)
}

# Define menu options
menuItems   <- c("Binomial", "Poisson", "Geometric", "Negative Binomial", "Hypergeometric", "Uniform", "Normal", "Exponential")

while(TRUE) {
  # Displays the menu
  choice <- displayMenu(menuItems)

  if(choice == 1) {
    print("Good choice!")
    break
  } else {
    print("Bad choice.")
    break
  }
}
```

I expected it to give me a menu interface, but instead all I got was

```
source('~/Desktop/Quantitative Finance /R data scripts for statistics/QF_Probability_Distribution.R')
```

Comment: Two things: `inputNumber` should return `num` instead of breaking. And your 'output' is the expression that needs to be executed to source the file. Where is the cursor when you source the code?

Comment: @Rohit I don't understand what you're asking. I pressed the "Source" button in Rstudio expecting everything to run. Previously, I have set the working directory to be the one above

Comment: Try pasting `source('QF_Probability_Distribution.R')` in the console and pressing enter

Comment: @Rohit Nope, still doesn't work unfortunately :(